# TypeScript feild's type depend on another field's type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to write an interpreter by TypeScript. This language has 2 primitive types and I define them as follows.

```js
type DataType = { kind: 'number' } | {kind: 'string' }
```

and then I would like to define another type that also include it's instance.

```js
type _DataType<T extends 'type' | 'typedValue'> = {
    kind: 'number',
    value: T extends 'type' ? undefined : number,
} | {
    kind: 'string'
    value: T extends 'type' ? undefined : string,
}
type DataType = _DataType<'type'>;
type TypedValue = _DataType<'typedValue'>;
```

It works well. But when I want to define a higher order type like array which can take original `DataType` as parameter. I don't know how to define it. Below is what I tried:

```js
type _HigherType<T extends 'type' | 'typedValue'> = {
    kind: 'Array',
    t: DataType,
    value: Array<?????>
} | {
    kind: 'Single',
    t: DataType,
    value: ?????
}
type HigherType = _HigherType<'type'>;
type HigherTypedValue = _HigherType<'typedValue'>;
```

It seems that the `value`'s type depends on `t`'s type, but how to express their relation?

Maybe I could just expand `HigherType` like below:

```js
type _HigherType<T extends 'type' | 'typedValue'> = {
    kind: 'Array',
    t: { kind: 'number },
    value: T extends 'type' ? undefined : Array<number>
} | {
    kind: 'Array',
    t: { kind: 'string' },
    value: T extends 'type' ? undefined : Array<string>
} | {
    kind: 'single',
    t: { kind: 'number' },
    value: T extends 'type' ? undefined : number
} | {
    kind: 'single',
    t: { kind: 'string' },
    value: T extends 'type' ? undefined : string
}
```

But If there are m DataType variants and n HigherType(despite Array, we may have Option, Set,......), we need to write m*n variants, and most of them have repeated part. Is there a way to only define m + n variants?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to express `m*n` in typescript system you should use distributivity.

Consider simple example:

```js
type All = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type Variants<T extends string> = T extends any ? { tag: T } : any


type Result_ = Variants<All> // union of all possible states

// WIthout distribution
type Variants2<T> = { tag: T }

type Result__=Variants2<All> // no union
```

YOu can also find [this article](https://catchts.com/permutations#second) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252446/is-it-possible-to-generate-string-literal-combinations-with-template-literal-in#answer-68256789) helpfull.

**Solution:**

```js
type Kinds = 'number' | 'string'
type Value = 'type' | 'typedValue'

/**
 * HashMap for type names
 */
type Dictionary = {
    number: number,
    string: string,
}

type HandleValue<V extends Value, Type> = V extends 'type' ? undefined : Type

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type DataType_<V extends Value> = Values<{
    [Prop in Kinds]: {
        kind: Prop,
        value: HandleValue<V, Dictionary[Prop]>
    }
}>


type DataType = DataType_<'type'>;
type TypedValue = DataType_<'typedValue'>;

type HigherTypes = 'Array' | 'single' //| 'Option' | 'Set'

/**
 * You should puth in this conditional type all allowed tpye constructors:
 * Array, Set, Options ....
 */
type MapStructure<Prop extends string, T extends DataType> =
    (Prop extends 'Array'
        ? Array<Dictionary[T['kind']]>
        : (Prop extends 'single'
            ? Dictionary[T['kind']]
            : never
        )
    )

type HigherOrderType<V extends Value, T extends DataType = DataType> =
    Values<{
        [Prop in HigherTypes]: (T extends any
            ? {
                kind: Prop,
                t: Pick<T, 'kind'>,
                value: HandleValue<V, MapStructure<Prop, T>>
            }
            : never)
    }>

type Result = HigherOrderType<'type'>

type _HigherType<T extends 'type' | 'typedValue'> = {
    kind: 'Array',
    t: { kind: 'number' },
    value: T extends 'type' ? undefined : Array<number>
} | {
    kind: 'Array',
    t: { kind: 'string' },
    value: T extends 'type' ? undefined : Array<string>
} | {
    kind: 'single',
    t: { kind: 'number' },
    value: T extends 'type' ? undefined : number
} | {
    kind: 'single',
    t: { kind: 'string' },
    value: T extends 'type' ? undefined : string
}


/**
 * Tests
 */
type HigherType = _HigherType<'type'> extends HigherOrderType<'type'> ? true : false; // true
type HigherTypedValue = _HigherType<'typedValue'> extends HigherOrderType<'typedValue'> ? true : false; // true
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA0gSwHYBMDOMC8MDkSCuAtgEZQBOOMAPrmiGcgOY6iSwBqAhgDb6zY5w0SjUFsUXXlBbAA9ACp5wGPJgAJTmgAWAWU4QYAMwD2ZGENhJOhKGmXzZraDAAiCAMYgExq2TBYYAG9lGFCCEnIALhhw0jIAGhDQugYkRmiUpkSAX2AnWA1UbihJPgAedhgoAA8QKFQMUqh4mAAVNgA%20AMqauobcC0oAfhh8VChDZCgUGGj26DyLGCa0Mtau7FaAbQBrKDBjQzaAXUW2V04QTnmoAH0Kqtr69GWePg3XqVXg0NCtgAUyMYDMh4Mh0Mdoj9fjCduDooDgYkYTCAG5vKDRQooYpNCotNyeby%20MAAoEQY4dJIwXLZKlnZwuS7Xc7YJlXG73MTCDoAbnybXETQC7JZ0C5FgkGJwfIZBQQjC05BuGAEAEEyGROGARLQmMVKLJZKIAPIQLw%20XU4ADKUBAMgUShUMAAmsZ8DBtO7uDMIPgQFoYKCAwgMO4fCgEBarNxzOceLGE8YAO7TcwQMCwcNIFL4TymNCRewwDVasAtW0gFpm6MYAB0Dbr9kcSz0EGt9DzIHwZCgZURBl6zwwmTSLVajz6L1FNw21IAFAPJ8PcKXtSwUb8RmuwGVCdHOH4ttscHDUDhjpTqTDoovycv%20jg0PrpNfNzARvviYfSSezygL1Od8UWiJAoFRcg31CABKalYIFNQFSVMgTTIFBlTYB4h36JpxwfadmRuEVCM6LBqRWMpoU3MlgSDJB1CQjDoDQSEYHnCdsJeTgkDAKCURGKjgJRf8EXJZEhM3EAEQ8HY1haU9wRlcSJLRDEsW4nESgxfEYDbDsyC7Hs%20wHccOipFSaT4m8YnA8hYJhOk5RgAAlWx8G4EAAkQxVyFQ9CyBuMpuWkekllubzkMCjinkfQZqAGIVpQ%20QSRNXTV12U8woRgVK8CIOJKGyTL0SkOZ8IwYLhlGcZJjAmZoh3MpYnIKlsnilL4TSsscEyqSghyzqn3oJhCuKtS2nKhLhA-ar0NqtMGvS3dR0YVr2upXLnzSA1euy3LmooGkxtKibOIquKRjGOapnqmJ8sgtqaA61BoifF8eupPrAgGl7aGGtJRupEq%20DKs6pukGaromG7Zk9f7GGAXI8kdYtWlsEA7BUFtzgipj%20BgcLGICzDKq6MHcZQtC8aCwYuhGTtYGiQweDQKBeRgI1zAMqAEKJm4pSkAJCZ84noBpxKpBlSaKb86ngoFvgpfp7nYeZ7hWfZzmGbyHWljVbhYwETgrWIK13BkJYuAYbiMbWSaVo%20aKpwwbj-AE8xOHSCa2uiV3dfOVy0HckBbm6Q8EBt1Z9e4LpObGYkYEOGAExgCBjDQZ9iGKOHLlsZHZBgAB1ABJAN3U8yNMmIf1iQFK2I6QDGACY1mSj2vYnJGlkD4PbluTB68jlvo9jgukGMariSAA)
If you want to distribute smth, just use `T extends any`.