# Optional element with literal type in tuple type

Tags: typescript, tuples

I try to create a read-only tuple type with optional elements. The list can be of any length and contain any of the three elements `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`. They are [Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), not `string` type.

This is my solution by now, it seems to work. This method has a disadvantage. If I have 100 different literal types, I need to add an optional symbol `?` after each element, which is very cumbersome

```
export interface FormAttributesConfig {
    list: readonly ['a'?, 'b'?, 'c'?];
}

const attr1: FormAttributesConfig = {
    list: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
const attr2: FormAttributesConfig = {
    list: ['a', 'b']
}
const attr3: FormAttributesConfig = {
    list: []
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMWgFsBBGGKBAIwFdUBnAYQiXQQHM4BvAKDn7gAbBPRgAuOFGCYAJi0EBPOAG0A5JlUB+ADRxVVLbtXYtAXQDcPAL48e2FqLiZyUAIwTCUUi+p1gTFjZOAF5uPgFhUQk1DSMDIxNTazsHeGcKACYPYjIKXwZmVg44UN4BIRFxFXVVONUkm3skR3SoAGZsr1zKWgLA4tLw-kiq5QagA)

**UPDATE:**

I can use `Partial` utility types to make all literal types in tuple optional.

```
export interface FormAttributesConfig {
    list: Partial<readonly ['a', 'b', 'c']>
}
```

I want to know if there are any disadvantages in this way or a better way?

Comment: There is a disadvantage. this type `[undefined]` is allowed. Does order of elements in the tuple matters?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks for the reply. The `undefined` value should not be allowed.  The order does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252446/is-it-possible-to-generate-string-literal-combinations-with-template-literal-in#answer-68256789
type Permutations<T extends string, U extends string = T> =
    T extends any ? (T | `${T} ${Permutations<Exclude<U, T>>}`) : never;

type ToArray<T extends string, Cache extends string[] = []> =
    (T extends `${infer Head} ${infer Tail}`
        ? ToArray<Tail, [...Cache, Head]>
        : (T extends `${infer Head}`
            ? [...Cache, Head]
            : Cache
        )
    )

type Util<T extends string> = ToArray<Permutations<T>> | []


export interface FormAttributesConfig {
    list: Util<'a' | 'b' | 'c'>
}

const attr1: FormAttributesConfig = {
    list: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}

const attr2: FormAttributesConfig = {
    list: ['a', 'b']
}

const attr3: FormAttributesConfig = {
    list: [] // allowed
}

const attr4: FormAttributesConfig = {
    list: [undefined] // error
}
```

`ToArray` splits string by empty symbol, just like `stirng.split(' ')` does.
It iterates recursively over the string and grabs first char

`Permutations` computes all possible permutations.

Please keep in mind, this util is not CPU friendly
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210910#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBbArsAhsAlgewHYGcAeAFSggA9gJcATfKfYeTXAcwBooBVMy6uhkxasoAXijEAfGIBQUeRN5Va9NLhBQA-FAAUpAD5QABgBIA3sQC%20Uc3CSoMOAoQCi5AMYAbZDQiEunFKSlkYAlFAAXFC4EABuCADcMjKgkBLYAILw8GggJEr89IzMbJwAwmjuABbQFMoCxcIA2gC6YlCt0qJyCnoFKsbmLABmCFAAEhBoNNZDuKPwEmiYniE9CgraxJnZuSTLnpxNAHSnFdUQnJPTLZLrG5G6pHWFg2YjY9czRvcPmx2nY7nGpXKY0Fq-P6PYEQSHyUL3BEpcDQLhYTz5F4DRpsLrpLI5PJ2FDoLB4IhBKCGVrJGQUMDYeDAKAsKjwYaVaAAMUZiAywCEACNUBB8GU8MNMCIzPdPJhGFE0StCAByNAqqlQFWCjWGFXuXVamiGlUQE3DE0AKxVd0syXc5OZGCYAEYojykPyhSKxRKpe0ZRs5QqOmqVZxteGtQaIXaZA6CE6BfAAEzu3le5jCqi%20%20b%208SBhTB4BRJphiM62P2x1QZ3wADM6c9ycw2dF4rzIgLsvlJY6bQA9APa55PNgAO4QGgyOMJxi15MAFibfJbbdzkq7UEL8mLpeQtAgkpi4KgQ7I2UZM6AA)