# Implicitly binding my Generic Constraint to my component property with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I recently got a [great suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69868940/17343404) to enforce type safety by using a generic constraint for types that would otherwise be too complex for TypeScript to compile.

My generic constraint `asTextSize` validates any `size` input that is passed to the `TextComponent` based on the following constraints:

A. Whether the value is a static text size (`small`, `medium` or `large`)

B. Or if the value consists of one or more breakpoint-specific text sizes (separated by a whitespace)
e.g. `small@medium medium@large`, `medium@large`, etc.

Currently, I have to call the constraint checker every time while passing a value to the `size` property of the component.

Would there instead be a way to implicitly bind this constraint to the `size` property of the component, so that each input is validated automatically?

```
type TextSize = 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
type Breakpoint = '@small' | '@medium' | '@large';

type CheckTextSize<T extends string, S extends string = TextSize, B extends string = Breakpoint> =
  | (T extends `${infer F} ${infer R}`
      ? F extends `${S}${infer BB}`
        ? `${F} ${BB extends B ? CheckTextSize<R, S, Exclude<B, BB>> : B}`
        : `${S}${B}`
      : T extends `${S}${infer BB}`
      ? BB extends B
        ? T
        : `${S}${B}`
      : `${S}${B}`)
  | TextSize;

const asTextSize = <T extends string>(x: CheckTextSize<T>): CheckTextSize<T> => x;

export class TextComponent {
  @Prop() public size?: string = asTextSize('medium');

  public render() {
    return <span>Some text...</span>;
  }
}

// Currently:
<TextComponent size={asTextSize('small@medium medium@large')} />;

// Preferred way:
<TextComponent size='small@medium medium@large' />;
```

I guess, in the end, I want something like:

```
public size?: CheckTextSize<T>
```

instead of:

```
public size?: string
```

Would something like this be possible or does it conflict with the idea of a generic constraint?