# TypeScript how to make recursive template literal type?

Tags: typescript

How to make recursive template literal type?

```
type MyType = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
type MyTypesWithDot = `??` 
// (o) 'A.B' 'A.C' 'B.C' 'A.B.C' 'A.A.B'
// (o) 'A.A.A.A.B.B.A.C.{TOO MANY MyType}.A.B' ...
// (x) 'A.D' 'A..D' 'A.BB'

function myFunc(myArg: MyType) {
  // some code
}
```

I tryed infer keyword, generic, some other way.. but I can't :(

Comment: Please see [here](https://tsplay.dev/WKpaow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252446/is-it-possible-to-generate-string-literal-combinations-with-template-literal-in#answer-68256789).

Answer (score 1):

```js
type MyTypesWithDot<T extends string> = T extends MyType
  ? T
  : T extends `${infer A}.${infer B}`
  ? `${MyTypesWithDot<A>}.${MyTypesWithDot<B>}`
  : never

function myFunc<T extends string>(myArg: MyTypesWithDot<T>) {
  // some code
}
```

the point is apply a recursive check by

```js
T extends `${infer A}.${infer B}` ? `${MyTypesWithDot<A>}.${MyTypesWithDot<B>}`: never
```

and use `T extends MyType` to avoid infinite loop